# Custom delegate not getting called

Tags: ios, delegates

I am trying to use Delegates to communicate thru view controllers. Here is my code:

```
@protocol ViewControllerDelegate;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{


    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *dateTimePicker;

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *className;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *assignmentTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *assignmentDescription;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISwitch *procrastinationNotificationSwitch;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *notificationOnOffLabel;
@property (nonatomic, assign)  id <ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic,strong)classObject *classObject;
-(IBAction) addButton:(id)sender;


@end
@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)assignmentSaved:(classObject *)classObj;
```

In action:

```
[self.delegate assignmentSaved:self.classObject];
```

In other view controller:

```
-(ViewController *)vc
{
    if (!_vc) {
        _vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    }

    return _vc;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.vc.delegate = self;
}

-(void)assignmentSaved:(classObject *)classObj
{
    NSLog(@"%@",classObj.description);
    classObj2 = classObj;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

vc is a property of `View Controller`. When I NSLog the delegate, the delegate ends up to be nil. Also I tried @mialkan answer yet it still does not work. If you need any more info just ask.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Is `self.delegate` `nil`?  Are you not seeing the log in `assignmentSaved:`?

Comment: @jszumski The problem is that the delegate method is not getting called.

Comment: @jszumski No I do not see the NSLog

Comment: Is it `nil`?  Try changing the property to `weak` or `unsafe_unretained`.

Comment: @jszumski The delegate is null

Comment: @jszumski I tried weak but the delegate remains null

Comment: Is `self` deallocated at some point after `self.vc.delegate = self;`?  Put a breakpoint in `dealloc` and see if its hit sometime before you expect the delegate method to fire.

Comment: @jszumski The delegate method is called first

Comment: have you declared <ViewControllerDelegate> in header file?

Comment: Can you try self.vc in one step, and then do self.vc.delegate = self? I do believe if you do self.vc.delegate, first the accessor method will be called and allocate memory to _vc, and then only delegate property will be accessed. But still, can you check again once

Comment: @neeraj Still does not works and the delegate remains null.

Comment: What do you do with the `ViewController` that you return from `vc`?  Is it presented or otherwise put onto the screen somewhere?  Try logging `self` inside your action method and `_vc` when you return it.  If they're not the same value, you've found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes in your code, and dont forget to `@synthesize delegate;`  and dont for get to setDelegate:self where you create ViewController.

```
@protocol ViewControllerDelegate;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{


    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *dateTimePicker;
    id <ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *className;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *assignmentTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *assignmentDescription;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISwitch *procrastinationNotificationSwitch;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *notificationOnOffLabel;
@property (nonatomic, assign)  id <ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic,strong)classObject *classObject;
-(IBAction) addButton:(id)sender;


@end
@protocol ViewControllerDelegate

-(void)assignmentSaved:(classObject *)classObj;

@end
```

Comment: I think your problem is you can not setDelegate:self. in your viewDidLoad method check if cv is nil or not? I tried the delegation and it worked.

Comment: I did set the delegate to self...vc is not nill.

Comment: Do you have to use delegate method? You can use NotificationCenter

Comment: Yes I have to use the delegate

Comment: can you provide sample project to check it out?

Answer (score 0):

In the first view did you subscribe to your delegate **< ViewControllerDelegate >** ?

```
MyOtherViewController : UIViewController <ViewControllerDelegate>
```

and you can only do that :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (!_vc) 
        _vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];

    self.vc.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: _vc = [[ViewController alloc]init]; 
what is your init method ? it's a view create with a xib ?